# Can we restart Microsoft Azure app service from c#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, restart, appserver

I'm looking for a solution to restart the azure app server/app service from C#

Is there a solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

Not only in c# but almost in every language. Just call the REST API:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/restart?api-version=2019-08-01
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/restart

Comment: How can we find the below parameters from Azure portal :
string name, 
string resourceGroupName, 
string subscriptionId, 
string apiversion,
bool softRestart,
bool synchronous

Comment: all values can be found in your Azure Subscription.